# IBM JSF PortletSession is null

Tags: java, jsf, websphere, portal

We use **IBM WebSphere Portal** in combination with `JSF`. A *dreadful* mix, which keeps proving its dreadfulness time after time.

Recently we're having the issue where we have a portlet with a *link* to a *download servlet* (contained in the *same war*). This *servlet* tries to read *certain attributes* from the *HttpSession* which are supposed to be set by the *portlet* on the *PortletSession* in `APPLICATION_SCOPE`.

Sometimes, however, the *servlet* couldn't *read* any of the needed attributes from the *`HttpSession`*. This was cause for an *investigation* by me. After some searching I discovered that it only happened when the *portlet* was *loaded* for the *first time* (without any page reloads).

After some experimenting I got a `NullPointerException` when calling `getAttributeNames(scope)` on the `PortletSession`. The `PortletSession` was obtained from the *external context* through the *faces context*.  I discovered the `PortletSession` was in fact a  `com.ibm.faces.portlet.httpbridge.PortletSessionWrapper` which apparently is *supposed to contain* the actual `PortletSession`. This contained *session* was clearly **null**. Most methods of the `PortletSessionWrapper` guard against an *NPE* with a null check, however, the `getAttributeNames(scope)`  didn't (a bug if you ask me).

**Now is the big question:** why is the (real) `PortletSession` ***null*** on the *first load* of the *portlet* ?

The `META-INF` of the *jsf-protletbrdige* providing the wrapper:

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>  Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1
>   Created-By: IBM Corporation
>  Specification-Title: Java Server
>   Faces
>  Implementation-Title: JSF Widget Library (JWL) - Portlet
>   Bridge
>  Implementation-Version: JWL v3_1_5
>   Implementation-Vendor: IBM
>  Build-Version: 20100212_0941
>   Build-Date: February 12 2010
>  Copyright-Info: Copyright (c)
>   2003,2008, International Business Machines Corporation.  All Rights
>   Reserved.

The stacktrace when calling the getAttributeNames(scope) method:

```
[21-8-12 17:52:16:051 CEST] 00000041 servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet Header in application PA_mytestportlet. Exception created : javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.portlet.PortletException: /MyPortletView.jsp(105,9) '#{MyPortletView.productId}' Error reading 'productId' on type mytest.portal.testportlet.view.MyPortletViewBean
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.doDispatch(PortletServlet.java:361)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:82)
    at com.ibm.isclite.container.collaborator.PortletServletCollaborator.doDispatch(PortletServletCollaborator.java:143)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.rrd.RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.doDispatch(RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.java:60)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.CacheCollaborator.doDispatch(CacheCollaborator.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.doDispatch(PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.java:121)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.dispatch(PortletServlet.java:208)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:165)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:104)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.webextension.PortletExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(PortletExtensionProcessor.java:86)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:686)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.invoke(PortletInvokerImpl.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:78)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.PortletInvokerCacheCollaborator.doRender(PortletInvokerCacheCollaborator.java:58)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.invoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:313)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doInvoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:101)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.invokePMI(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:163)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doInvoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doRender(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.render(PortletInvokerImpl.java:97)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerImpl.doRender(PortletContainerImpl.java:121)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:80)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.ExtCollaborator.doRender(ExtCollaborator.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.CacheInvokerCollaborator.doRender(CacheInvokerCollaborator.java:66)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerImpl.renderPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.pcinvoker.PortletInvokerImpl$2.run(PortletInvokerImpl.java:100)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:251)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.pcinvoker.PortletInvokerImpl.invokeRender(PortletInvokerImpl.java:96)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletInvokerImpl$1.invoke(PortletInvokerImpl.java:98)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.invoke(PortletInvokerImpl.java:181)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.invokeRender(PortletInvokerImpl.java:96)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.PortletContainerImpl.renderPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:116)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.PortletContainerImpl.doRenderPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:641)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.ext.render.AbstractRenderManager.performService(AbstractRenderManager.java:264)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.PortletContainerImpl.renderPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:132)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.tags.PortletRenderTag.doStartTag(PortletRenderTag.java:179)
    at com.ibm._jsp._Control._jspx_meth_portal$1skin_portletRender_0(_Control.java:276)
    at com.ibm._jsp._Control._jspx_meth_portal$1logic_if_1(_Control.java:315)
    at com.ibm._jsp._Control._jspService(_Control.java:168)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:259)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:686)
    at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.DispatcherServiceImpl.handleRequest(DispatcherServiceImpl.java:93)
    at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.DispatcherServiceImpl.include(DispatcherServiceImpl.java:53)
    at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.Dispatcher.include(Dispatcher.java:50)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.skins.Default.render(Default.java:154)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.SkinTemplate.render(SkinTemplate.java:68)
    at com.ibm.wps.composition.elements.Component.render(Component.java:638)
    at com.ibm.wps.composition.elements.Control.render(Control.java:159)
    at com.ibm.wps.composition.Composition.render(Composition.java:3102)
    at com.ibm.wps.composition.Composition.render(Composition.java:163)
    at com.ibm.websphere.personalization.transformation.PznTransformationLayoutModel.render(PznTransformationLayoutModel.java:90)
    at com.ibm.wps.model.wrappers.LayoutModelWrapperFactoryImpl$LayoutModelWrapperImpl.render(LayoutModelWrapperFactoryImpl.java:275)
    at com.ibm.wps.model.ModelUtil$WrappedCompositionModel.render(ModelUtil.java:1124)
    at com.ibm._jsp._UnlayeredContainer_2D_H._jspService(_UnlayeredContainer_2D_H.java:224)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:259)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:686)
    at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.DispatcherServiceImpl.handleRequest(DispatcherServiceImpl.java:93)
    at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.DispatcherServiceImpl.include(DispatcherServiceImpl.java:53)
    at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.Dispatcher.include(Dispatcher.java:50)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.skins.Default.render(Default.java:154)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.SkinTemplate.render(SkinTemplate.java:68)
    at com.ibm.wps.composition.elements.Component.render(Component.java:638)
    at com.ibm.wps.composition.Composition.render(Composition.java:3102)
    at com.ibm.wps.composition.Composition.render(Composition.java:163)
    at com.ibm.websphere.personalization.transformation.PznTransformationLayoutModel.render(PznTransformationLayoutModel.java:90)
    at com.ibm.wps.model.wrappers.LayoutModelWrapperFactoryImpl$LayoutModelWrapperImpl.render(LayoutModelWrapperFactoryImpl.java:275)
    at com.ibm.wps.model.ModelUtil$WrappedCompositionModel.render(ModelUtil.java:1124)
    at com.ibm._jsp._UnlayeredContainer_2D_V._jspService(_UnlayeredContainer_2D_V.java:215)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:259)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:686)
    at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.DispatcherServiceImpl.handleRequest(DispatcherServiceImpl.java:93)
    at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.DispatcherServiceImpl.include(DispatcherServiceImpl.java:53)
    at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.Dispatcher.include(Dispatcher.java:50)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.skins.Default.render(Default.java:154)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.SkinTemplate.render(SkinTemplate.java:68)
    at com.ibm.wps.composition.elements.Component.render(Component.java:638)
    at com.ibm.wps.composition.Composition.render(Composition.java:3102)
    at com.ibm.wps.composition.Composition.render(Composition.java:163)
    at com.ibm.websphere.personalization.transformation.PznTransformationLayoutModel.render(PznTransformationLayoutModel.java:90)
    at com.ibm.wps.model.wrappers.LayoutModelWrapperFactoryImpl$LayoutModelWrapperImpl.render(LayoutModelWrapperFactoryImpl.java:275)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.tags2.PageRenderTag.doStartTag(PageRenderTag.java:534)
    at com.ibm._jsp._Home._jspService(_Home.java:104)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:259)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:686)
    at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.DispatcherServiceImpl.handleRequest(DispatcherServiceImpl.java:93)
    at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.DispatcherServiceImpl.include(DispatcherServiceImpl.java:53)
    at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.Dispatcher.include(Dispatcher.java:50)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.screens.Default.render(Default.java:133)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.ScreenTemplate.render(ScreenTemplate.java:59)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.tags2.ScreenRenderTag.doStartTag(ScreenRenderTag.java:182)
    at com.ibm._jsp._Default._jspx_meth_portal$1core_screenRender_0(_Default.java:3623)
    at com.ibm._jsp._Default._jspService(_Default.java:1966)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:259)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:686)
    at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.DispatcherServiceImpl.handleRequest(DispatcherServiceImpl.java:93)
    at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.DispatcherServiceImpl.include(DispatcherServiceImpl.java:53)
    at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.Dispatcher.include(Dispatcher.java:50)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.themes.Default.doDispatch(Default.java:294)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.themes.Default.render(Default.java:247)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.ThemeTemplate.render(ThemeTemplate.java:65)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPRenderPhase.processRendering(WPRenderPhase.java:509)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPBaseRenderPhase.execute(WPBaseRenderPhase.java:194)
    at com.ibm.wps.state.phases.AbstractRenderPhase.next(AbstractRenderPhase.java:106)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPAbstractRenderPhase.next(WPAbstractRenderPhase.java:97)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.callPortal(Servlet.java:860)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.doGet(Servlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.doFilter(Servlet.java:1257)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.ContentHandlerCleanup.doFilter(ContentHandlerCleanup.java:648)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:93)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.service(Servlet.java:1248)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.ExtendedLocaleFilter.doFilter(ExtendedLocaleFilter.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.friendly.servlet.FriendlySelectionFilter.doFilter(FriendlySelectionFilter.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.wps.mappingurl.impl.URLAnalyzer.doFilter(URLAnalyzer.java:381)
 . . .
Caused by: javax.portlet.PortletException: /MyPortletView.jsp(105,9) '#{MyPortletView.productId}' Error reading 'productId' on type mytest.portal.testportlet.view.MyPortletViewBean
    at com.ibm.faces.portlet.FacesPortlet.doRender(FacesPortlet.java:384)
    at com.ibm.faces.portlet.FacesPortlet.doView(FacesPortlet.java:413)
    at com.ibm.faces.portlet.FacesPortlet.doDispatch(FacesPortlet.java:301)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
    at mytest.portal.testportlet.portlet.HeaderPortlet.render(HeaderPortlet.java:44)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:128)
    at com.ibm.wps.propertybroker.standard.filter.C2APortletFilter.doFilter(C2APortletFilter.java:183)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:120)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.doDispatch(PortletServlet.java:573)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.ibm.isclite.container.collaborator.PortletServletCollaborator.doRender(PortletServletCollaborator.java:71)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:105)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.rrd.RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.doRender(RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:105)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.CacheCollaborator.doRender(CacheCollaborator.java:92)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:105)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.doRender(PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.java:156)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:105)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.doDispatch(PortletServlet.java:273)
    ... 203 more
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.el.JspELException: /MyPortletView.jsp(105,9) '#{MyPortletView.productId}' Error reading 'productId' on type mytest.portal.testportlet.view.MyPortletViewBean
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression.getValue(JspValueExpression.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.UIParameter.getValue(UIParameter.java:167)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getParamList(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:518)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.OutputLinkRenderer.renderAsActive(OutputLinkRenderer.java:203)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.OutputLinkRenderer.encodeBegin(OutputLinkRenderer.java:100)
    at com.ibm.faces.renderkit.DefaultAjaxRenderer.encodeBegin(DefaultAjaxRenderer.java:64)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:812)
    at mytest.jsf.util.ChildRendererUtil.renderChildren(ChildRendererUtil.java:45)
    at mytest.portal.ui.jsf.custom.component.htmltag.HtmlTagRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlTagRenderer.java:110)
    at com.ibm.faces.renderkit.DefaultAjaxRenderer.encodeChildren(DefaultAjaxRenderer.java:73)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:836)
    at mytest.jsf.util.ChildRendererUtil.renderChildren(ChildRendererUtil.java:47)
    at mytest.portal.ui.jsf.custom.component.htmltag.HtmlTagRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlTagRenderer.java:110)
    at com.ibm.faces.renderkit.DefaultAjaxRenderer.encodeChildren(DefaultAjaxRenderer.java:73)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:836)
    at mytest.jsf.util.ChildRendererUtil.renderChildren(ChildRendererUtil.java:47)
    at mytest.portal.ui.jsf.custom.component.htmltag.HtmlTagRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlTagRenderer.java:110)
    at com.ibm.faces.renderkit.DefaultAjaxRenderer.encodeChildren(DefaultAjaxRenderer.java:73)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:836)
    at mytest.jsf.util.ChildRendererUtil.renderChildren(ChildRendererUtil.java:47)
    at mytest.portal.ui.jsf.custom.component.htmltag.HtmlTagRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlTagRenderer.java:110)
    at com.ibm.faces.renderkit.DefaultAjaxRenderer.encodeChildren(DefaultAjaxRenderer.java:73)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:836)
    at mytest.jsf.util.ChildRendererUtil.renderChildren(ChildRendererUtil.java:47)
    at mytest.portal.ui.jsf.custom.component.htmltag.HtmlTagRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlTagRenderer.java:110)
    at com.ibm.faces.renderkit.DefaultAjaxRenderer.encodeChildren(DefaultAjaxRenderer.java:73)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:836)
    at mytest.jsf.util.ChildRendererUtil.renderChildren(ChildRendererUtil.java:47)
    at mytest.portal.ui.jsf.custom.component.htmltag.HtmlTagRenderer.encodeChildren(HtmlTagRenderer.java:110)
    at com.ibm.faces.renderkit.DefaultAjaxRenderer.encodeChildren(DefaultAjaxRenderer.java:73)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:836)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:936)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:942)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:148)
    at com.ibm.faces.renderkit.DefaultAjaxRenderer.encodeChildren(DefaultAjaxRenderer.java:73)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:836)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:936)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:942)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.doRenderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:223)
    at com.ibm.faces.portlet.PortletViewHandlerImpl.renderView(PortletViewHandlerImpl.java:79)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at com.ibm.faces.portlet.FacesPortlet.doRender(FacesPortlet.java:372)
    ... 221 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.faces.portlet.httpbridge.PortletSessionWrapper.getAttributeNames(PortletSessionWrapper.java:185)
    at mytest.portal.testportlet.view.MyPortletViewBean.getProductId(MyPortletViewBean.java:394)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:64)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:143)
    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:73)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:102)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:263)
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression.getValue(JspValueExpression.java:100)
    ... 265 more
```

The session scope is obtained using the following code:

```
FacesContext facesContext = getFacesContext();
if (facesContext != null) {
    return (PortletSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(createIfNotExist);
 }
 return null;
```

where `createIfNotExist` is **false**.

Comment: What [portlet](http://www.bluesunrise.com/portlet-api/javax/portlet/Portlet.html) method is in the NPE stack trace? E.g. `init`, `render`, etc. You'll be looking for the `FacesPortlet` unless you've extended it.

Comment: Added the stacktrace for clarifaction. Seems to occur in the render phase.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this using a 2009 or 2011 build of jsf-portletbridge.jar (though I guess it could have been broken then fixed in the meantime.) What code do you use to get the session from the JSF context?

Comment: Added the code for obtaining the JSF context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a defect in the jsf-portletbridge.jar `PortletRequestWrapper` type. The JSF reference implementation is written to the servlet spec. The request wrapper implements `HttpServletRequest`. [`ExternalContext.getSession(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getSession%28boolean%29) will invoke [`HttpServletRequest.getSession(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28boolean%29). This will return a decorator object `PortletSessionWrapper` that implements both  `HttpSession` and `PortletSession`. It sounds like request decorator returns a session decorator even when the underlying `PortletSession` is null.

I'd try code of this form:

```
    PortletRequest request = (PortletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                                                          .getExternalContext()
                                                          .getRequest();
    PortletSession session = request.getPortletSession(false);
    if (session == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        return session.getAttribute("foo", PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
    }
```

Comment: As you could see in my question, I noted that that part was probably indeed a bug. The core of my question however was: why IS the portletSession null?

Comment: You stated "`createIfNotExist` is false". Assuming no other requests create a session before you render the portlet, the session will be null as [mandated by the API](http://www.bluesunrise.com/portlet-api/javax/portlet/PortletRequest.html#getPortletSession%28boolean%29). _JSF will usually create a session to hold the view in, but this doesn't happen until after the [render response](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jsf2/) phase._ The bug isn't that the wrapper doesn't do a null check; the external context should return null.

Comment: Now that comes closer to answering my question as to why the session is null. So it shouldn't get a JSF session until after the render response phase of the JSF. <br/>

Comment: Concerning the bug: when looking at the bridge code, you can clearly see that a lot of the methods of the SessionWrapper take into account that the contained session can be null. So it seems like they thought the contained session could be null and in that sense the bug would be not catching the null object in the getAttributeNumes method. I agree with you that the contained session should never be null and if the session was null, then the sessionwrapper should be null.